# Firebase cloud messaging not work sdk java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

When I run the code in the main class it runs perfectly, but in the backend, it does not work.

there are no thrown exceptions.
There are no such signs of errors.

I put impressions to see what happened but it never shows the impression 3.

> java version : 1.8 
>   server : glassfish 5

The code works in the main class but not in the backend, I thought it was because it was running on my local server(localhost), but it was uploaded to the server and the same thing happens, the code does not work and shows no errors

used maven dependence

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>6.4.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

imports generated

> import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
>       import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.AndroidConfig;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.AndroidNotification;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.ApnsConfig;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.Aps;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.Notification;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.TopicManagementResponse;
>       import com.google.firebase.messaging.WebpushConfig;

Code works in the main

```
try {
        System.out.println("1");

FileInputStream serviceAccount= new FileInputStream("/serviceAccountKey.json");
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setServiceAccountId("projectId")
                .setProjectId("projectId")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        System.out.println("2");

        com.google.firebase.messaging.Message message = 
            com.google.firebase.messaging.Message.builder()
                .putData("tipo", "cargueTareasFinalizado")
                .putData("nombreAmigo", "DARIOOO")
                .putData("pagina", "DARIOOO")
                .setToken(token)
                .setNotification(new Notification(
                        "Dario up 1.43% on the day",
                        "$GOOG gained 11.80 points to close at 835.67, up 
                         1.43% on the day."))
                .setAndroidConfig(AndroidConfig.builder()
                        .setTtl(3600 * 1000)
                        .setNotification(AndroidNotification.builder()
                                .setTitle("titulo android")
                                .setBody("body android")
                                .setIcon("icon_color")
                                .setColor("#247c2e")
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .setApnsConfig(ApnsConfig.builder()
                        .setAps(Aps.builder()
                                .setBadge(0)
                                .build())
                        .putCustomData("titulo", "tiiiiiiii")
                        .putCustomData("body", "bodddd")
                        .putCustomData("tipo", "cargueTareasFinalizado")
                        .build())
                .setWebpushConfig(WebpushConfig.builder()
                        .putData("titulo", "Tiiiiii")
                        .putData("body", "bodddy")
                        .putData("icon", "\"images/favicon.png\"")
                        .build())
                .build();

       System.out.println("3");

        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
```